# Is every natural number representable as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \pm k^3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A well known identity is: $$(n+3)^2 - (n+2)^2-(n+1)^2 + n^2 = 4$$

and using this identity we prove that the set $\displaystyle \{\pm 1^2, \pm 1^2 \pm 2^2,\pm 1^2\pm 2^2\pm 3^2, \cdots\}$ contains every natural number greater than or equal to $1$.But for establishing this result we need to verify representation of the numbers $1,2,3,4$ in the form $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \pm k^2$.

My question is can we say the same about the set of numbers $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \pm k^3$, that is if every natural number greater than or equal to $1$ is representable in this form.

What about the general case $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \pm k^s$ ?

This [**post**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079575/generalisation-of-n32-n22-n12n2-4) shows how to compute the constant, $\displaystyle C_s = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^s} \pm k^{s} =  \large{2^{\frac{s(s-1)}{2}}s!}$ where, the signs $\pm$ are chosen as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078649/is-every-natural-number-representable-as-sum-limits-k-1n-pm-k3?noredirect=1#comment2196490_1079247).

Comment: Exponent 4 was asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027877/alternating-sums-of-fourth-powers/1027893#1027893)  There is a paper cited that is supposed to solve the exponent 3 problem as well, but I am not able to view Postscript so far.

Comment: @RossMillikan, see http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.79.5129 for a PDF (see cached).

Comment: @lhf Thanks ! :-)

Comment: @RossMillikan: There is an identity, $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{7112}\pm(x+k)^5 = 480$$ so all that remains is to test all integers $1<N<240$. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084103/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will have to look a bit farther.  A similar identity to the one you cite:
 $$(n+7)^3-(n+6)^3-(n+5)^3+(n+4)^3-(n+3)^3+(n+2)^3+(n+1)^3-n^3=48$$ means we just need to solve the problem for $[-23,24]$ and because the exponent is odd we can consider opposite signs equivalent.  Because the cubes are spaced further than the squares it will probably take a bunch of searching to fill in all of $[1,24]$.  Of course, $1,7,9,18,20$ are easy.

Comment: It did not take too much searching to fill in $\{1, \dotsc, 24\}$; see my post below. Exponent 3 is solved!

Comment: (+1) Similar identities for higher values of $s$ can be derived using the Thue-Morse sequence for choosing the signs. So the problem is virtually solved for any value of $s$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I guess will need $2^s$ terms to eliminate all but  the constant terms in the identity I think. Is there a particular algo for doing it for each case $s$ ? :-) How do we use the Thue-Morse sequence to construct the same ?

Comment: @RossMillikan Is there a way to avoid the brute-*code*-attack on the verification problem ? :)

Comment: @r9m:  I don't know of one. To use Thue-Morse, given the signs for $s$, the signs for $s+1$ start with the same series, then you append the same series with the signs flipped $+ \leftrightarrow -$.  You can see that operation when I went from $s=2$ to $s=3$

Comment: @RossMillikan I get it now ! Thanks :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio:  You are right there is an identity like this that reduces the sum to a constant for all powers.  We don't have a proof that one can satisfy all the required sums (here $[1,24]$, much larger for higher exponents.)

Answer (score 15):

Consider this an addendum to Ross's answer. Found by a Python script which ran while I dined.

$1 = 1^3$ (at least 7 other ways)

$2 = 1^3 - 2^3 + 3^3 - 4^3 + 5^3 + 6^3 + 7^3 - 8^3 - 9^3 + 10^3 + 11^3 - 12^3$ (at least 12 other ways)

$3 = 1^3 - 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 + 6^3 - 7^3 + 8^3 - 9^3 + 10^3 - 11^3 - 12^3 + 13^3$ (at least 6 other ways)

$4 = -1^3 - 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 - 5^3 + 6^3 + 7^3 - 8^3$ (at least 18 other ways)

$5 = -1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 - 4^3 + 5^3 - 6^3 + 7^3 + 8^3 - 9^3$ (at least 6 other ways)

$6 = 1^3 - 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 - 5^3 + 6^3 + 7^3 - 8^3$ (at least 14 other ways)

$7 = -1^3 + 2^3$ (at least 12 other ways)

$8 = 1^3 + 2^3 - 3^3 + 4^3 - 5^3 + 6^3 + 7^3 - 8^3 - 9^3 + 10^3 - 11^3 - 12^3 + 13^3 - 14^3 + 15^3$ (at least 12 other ways)

$9 = 1^3 + 2^3$ (at least 13 other ways)

$10 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 - 4^3 + 5^3 - 6^3 - 7^3 + 8^3 + 9^3 - 10^3 + 11^3 + 12^3 - 13^3 + 14^3 - 15^3$ (at least 16 other ways)

$11 = 1^3 + 2^3 - 3^3 + 4^3 - 5^3 + 6^3 - 7^3 - 8^3 + 9^3$ (at least 5 other ways)

$12 = -1^3 - 2^3 - 3^3 - 4^3 + 5^3 + 6^3 - 7^3 + 8^3 - 9^3 - 10^3 + 11^3$ (at least 15 other ways)

$13 = -1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 - 4^3 - 5^3 + 6^3 + 7^3 - 8^3 - 9^3 + 10^3 - 11^3 + 12^3 + 13^3 - 14^3$ (possibly other ways)

$14 = 1^3 - 2^3 - 3^3 - 4^3 + 5^3 + 6^3 - 7^3 + 8^3 - 9^3 - 10^3 + 11^3$ (at least 9 other ways)

$15 = -1^3 + 2^3 - 3^3 - 4^3 - 5^3 - 6^3 - 7^3 + 8^3 - 9^3 + 10^3$ (at least 1 other way)

$16 = 1^3 - 2^3 - 3^3 - 4^3 + 5^3 - 6^3 - 7^3 - 8^3 + 9^3 - 10^3 + 11^3$ (at least 10 other ways)

$17 = 1^3 + 2^3 - 3^3 - 4^3 - 5^3 - 6^3 - 7^3 + 8^3 - 9^3 + 10^3$ (at least 6 other ways)

$18 = -1^3 - 2^3 + 3^3$ (at least 17 other ways)

$19 = 1^3 - 2^3 - 3^3 + 4^3 - 5^3 + 6^3 - 7^3 + 8^3 + 9^3 - 10^3$ (at least 8 other ways)

$20 = 1^3 - 2^3 + 3^3$ (at least 19 other ways)

$21 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 - 6^3 - 7^3 - 8^3 + 9^3 + 10^3 - 11^3 - 12^3 + 13^3$ (at least 5 other ways)

$22 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 - 5^3 + 6^3 + 7^3 - 8^3$ (at least 10 other ways)

$23 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 - 5^3 - 6^3 + 7^3 + 8^3 - 9^3 + 10^3 - 11^3 - 12^3 + 13^3$ (at least 5 other ways)

$24 = 1^3 + 2^3 - 3^3 - 4^3 + 5^3 + 6^3 - 7^3 + 8^3 + 9^3 + 10^3 - 11^3 + 12^3 + 13^3 + 14^3 - 15^3 - 16^3$ (at least 7 other ways)

Each of the above representations is the shortest possible.
The algorithm created a sequence of sets $S_n$ with $S_0 = \{0\}$ and $S_n = \{x+n^3, x-n^3 : x \in S_{n-1}\}$ for $n > 0$,
so that $S_1 = \{1, -1\}$, $S_2 = \{9, -7, 7, -9\}$, etc.
The algorithm also kept track of the sequence of signs used to arrive at each particular number.

Comment: Nice work ! :D Thank's !!!

Comment: @Unit: Do you suppose you can do the same for at least $1<N<100$ for $5$th powers? Kindly refer to my answer below.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Ahh, I just read this message. I will try, though it seems alexwlchan is almost there.

Comment: @Unit: And it seems Zander even managed $0\leq N<10000$. The ingenuity of some people never ceases to amaze.

Answer (score 6):

For 5th powers, there is an identity,

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{168}\pm(x+k)^5 = 480$$

analogous to the 3d powers mentioned by R. Millikan in his answer.

What remains to be shown is that all $0\leq N<240$ can be decomposed into sums of fifth powers. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084103/).

(**P.S.** The number of addends can be reduced to just $m=168$.)