# Can every natural number be written as a sum of signed odd squares?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Let $c_n \in \{ -1,1\}$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1078649/592365), it is stated that every natural number may be written as

$$\sum c_kk^2$$

Where $k$ runs from $1$ to some finite number. I am wondering whether every natural number $n$ can be written as follows:

$$n = \sum c_n(2k-1)^2.$$

In other words,

> can every natural number be written as the sum of the first so-and-so signed odd squares?

Obviously, $1=1^2$. However, even to find such a writing of $2$, I needed eight squares: 
$$2=1+9+25-49+81-121-169+225$$
And could not find one for $3$. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: For any four consecutive odd squares $a^2-(a+2)^2-(a+4)^2+(a+6)^2=16$, so if we can make 1 to 16 inclusive then we're done.

Comment: If you can show that any $n \in [0, 8]$ can be written in that form, then any $n \in [-7, -1]$ can also be written (reverse the signs), and therefore any $n \in [-7, 8]$ can be expressed as desired. Then induction would follow: If $n$ can be expressed, then $$n + 16 = n +(2k+7)^2 - (2k+5)^2-(2k+3)^2 + (2k+1)^2$$ can be expressed as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How high do you have to go?
$$1=+1^2$$
$$2=+1^2+3^2+5^2-7^2+9^2-11^2-13^2+15^2$$
$$3=+1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2-9^2$$
$$4=-1^2-3^2-5^2-7^2+9^2-11^2-13^2+15^2-17^2+19^2$$
$$5=+1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2-9^2+11^2+13^2+15^2+17^2-19^2-21^2$$
$$6=-1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2-9^2+11^2$$
$$7=+1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+9^2+11^2+13^2+15^2+17^2-19^2+21^2-23^2-25^2-27^2+29^2$$
$$8=-1^2+3^2$$
$$9=-1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2-9^2-11^2-13^2-15^2-17^2+19^2-21^2-23^2-25^2-27^2+29^2+31^2+33^2$$
$$10=+1^2+3^2$$
$$11=-1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2-9^2-11^2-13^2-15^2+17^2-19^2-21^2+23^2+25^2$$
$$12=-1^2-3^2-5^2-7^2-9^2+11^2-13^2+15^2$$
$$13=-1^2-3^2-5^2-7^2+9^2+11^2-13^2-15^2+17^2$$
$$14=-1^2-3^2-5^2+7^2$$
$$15=-1^2-3^2+5^2$$
$$16=+1^2-3^2-5^2+7^2$$
$$17=+1^2-3^2+5^2$$
$$18=+1^2+3^2-5^2+7^2-9^2+11^2+13^2-15^2$$
$$19=+1^2+3^2+5^2-7^2+9^2+11^2-13^2$$
$$20=-1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2-9^2-11^2-13^2-15^2+17^2+19^2$$
$$21=+1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+9^2+11^2+13^2-15^2-17^2-19^2+21^2$$
$$22=+1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2-9^2-11^2-13^2-15^2+17^2+19^2$$
$$23=+1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+9^2+11^2+13^2-15^2+17^2+19^2-21^2+23^2+25^2-27^2-29^2$$
$$24=-1^2+3^2+5^2-7^2-9^2+11^2$$
$$25=-1^2-3^2-5^2-7^2-9^2-11^2+13^2+15^2-17^2-19^2-21^2-23^2-25^2-27^2+29^2+31^2+33^2$$
$$26=+1^2+3^2+5^2-7^2-9^2+11^2$$
$$27=-1^2-3^2-5^2-7^2-9^2-11^2+13^2-15^2+17^2-19^2+21^2$$
$$28=+1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+9^2-11^2-13^2+15^2+17^2-19^2$$
$$29=+1^2-3^2-5^2-7^2-9^2-11^2+13^2-15^2+17^2-19^2+21^2$$
$$30=-1^2+3^2-5^2-7^2-9^2+11^2-13^2+15^2$$

Comment: No higher. See the comments to the OP by myself and Catalin Zara.

Comment: @nickgard Cool. This program runs pretty much instantaneously. Do you guys have more fun challenges while it's in my view?

Answer (score 6):

This is possible if $c_k \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$. For each $m$, consider that
$$1 = (2m + 1)^2 + (m^2 + m - 1)^2 - (m^2 + m + 1)^2,$$
which is a sum/difference of odd squares. Note also that the minimal square, $(2m + 1)^2$, can be made as large as we want, hence we can make $1$ as many times as we want without reusing squares. Thus, to make any $n$, we simply need to make $1$ $n$ times, out of different odd squares, and sum the result.

(As a bonus, we can make each $n$ out of odd squares in this way infinitely many ways, as we can subtract $1$s as well as we like.)

Comment: Would you be using _all_ squares from 1 to $\max$? Note that $c_k \in \{ -1, 1\}$.

Comment: I failed to notice that condition. I'll leave my answer here, given the partial results already posted.

Answer (score 3):

Shortest representations of small positive integers.

\begin{align*}
1 &= 1  \\
2 &= 1 + 9 + 25 - 49 + 81 - 121 - 169 + 225  \\
3 &= 1 + 9 + 25 + 49 - 81  \\
4 &= -1-9-25-49+81-121-169+225-289+361  \\
5 &= 1+9+25+49-81+121+169+225+289-361-441  \\
6 &= -1-9+25-49-81+121  \\
7 &= 1+9+25-49+81+121+169+225+289+361+441+529-625-729-841  \\
  &= 1+9+25+49+81+121+169+225+289-361+441-529-625-729+841 \\
8 &= -1+9  \\
9 &= -1-9-25-49-81+121-169-225-289-361-441-529+625+729+841+961-1089  \\
  &= -1-9+25-49-81-121-169-225-289+361-441-529-625-729+841+961+1089  \\
10 &= 1 + 9  \\
11 &= -1-9+25-49-81-121-169-225+289-361-441+529+625  \\
12 &= -1-9-25-49-81+121-169+225  \\
13 &= -1-9-25-49+81+121-169-225+289  \\
14 &= -1-9-25+49  \\
15 &= -1-9+25  \\
16 &= 1-9-25+49  \\
17 &= 1-9+25  \\
18 &= 1+9-25+49-81+121+169-225  \\
19 &= 1+9+25-49+81+121-169  \\
20 &= -1-9+25-49-81-121-169-225+289+361  \\
21 &= 1+9+25+49+81+121+169-225-289-361+441  \\
22 &= -1-9+25-49-81+121+169-225-289+361  \\
  &= -1+9-25-49+81-121-169+225-289+361  \\
  &= 1-9+25-49-81-121-169-225+289+361  \\
23 &= 1+9+25+49+81+121+169-225+289+361-441+529+625-729-841  \\
24 &= -1-9+25+49+81-121  \\
  &= -1+9+25-49-81+121  \\
25 &= -1-9-25-49-81-121-169-225-289-361+441+529+625+729-841+961-1089  \\
  &= -1-9-25-49-81-121-169+225-289-361-441+529-625+729+841+961-1089  \\
  &= -1-9-25-49-81-121-169-225+289-361+441-529+625-729+841-961+1089  \\
  &= 1-9-25-49-81-121-169-225-289-361-441-529+625+729+841-961+1089  \\
  &= -1-9-25-49-81-121+169-225-289-361+441-529+625-729-841+961+1089  \\
  &= -1-9-25-49+81-121-169-225-289-361-441+529+625-729-841+961+1089  \\
  &= -1-9-25-49-81-121+169+225-289-361-441-529-625-729+841+961+1089  \\
26 &= 1-9+25+49+81-121  \\
  &= 1+9+25-49-81+121  \\
27 &= -1-9-25-49-81-121+169-225+289-361+441  \\
28 &= -1+9+25+49+81+121+169+225-289-361  \\
  &= 1+9+25+49+81-121-169+225+289-361  \\
29 &= -1-9-25-49+81-121+169-225+289+361-441  \\
  &= -1-9+25-49-81-121-169+225+289+361-441  \\
  &= -1-9-25+49-81+121-169-225+289-361-441  \\
  &= 1-9-25-49-81-121+169-225+289-361+441  \\
30 &= -1-9-25+49+81-121-169+225  \\
  &= -1+9-25-49-81+121-169+225  \\
31 &= -1-9+25+49-81-121+169  \\
32 &= -1+9-25+49  \\
33 &= -1+9+25  \\
34 &= 1+9-25+49  \\
35 &= 1+9+25  \\
36 &= -1-9-25-49-81-121+169+225+289-361  \\
37 &= -1+9+25+49+81+121+169=225-289+361+441-529-625  \\
  &= 1+9+25+49+81-121-169+225+289+361+441-529-625  \\
  &= 1+9+25+49+81+121-169+225-289-361+441+529-625  \\
38 &= -1-9-25+49-81+121-169+225+289-361  \\
  &= 1-9-25-49-81-121+169+225+289-361  \\
  &= -1+9+25-49-81-121-169-225+289+361  \\
39 &= 1+9+25+49+81+121+169+225-289+361+441-529-625  \\
40 &= -1-9+25-49+81+121+169-225+289-361  \\
  &= 1-9-25+49-81+121-169+225+289-361  \\
  &= -1-9+25+49+81-121+169-225-289+361 \\
  &= -1+9+25-49-81+121+169-225-289+361  \\
  &= 1+9+25-49-81-121-169-225+289+361
\end{align*}

Comment: Oops, you are right, I did indeed misunderstand the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$$ $$3=1+9+25+49-81$$